# Jquery Validate plugin - Multiple fields in one Remote call

Tags: jquery, authentication, validation

I'm trying to use JQuerys validate plugin for a login screen. I want to use the remote option to check if the username and the password are found in my database. I got remote calls working for one field, but can't figure out how to bundle the two fields together into one remote call. Is this possible?

Here's the stripped down version of what I'm doing (completely standard, might not work because I removed/changed some stuff from my version to make it smaller):

Code for the form (in Jade):

```
form#loginForm.users(method='post', action='/login')
  fieldset
      legend Login
      .clearfix
        .input
          input.required(id='username', name='user[username]', type='text', remote='/checkUsername/')
      .clearfix
        .input
          input.required(id='password', name='user[password]', type='password')
      .actions
        input.btn.primary(type='submit', value='Login')
```

And then simply:

```
$('#loginForm').validate()
```

Comment: include the code you currently have and you might get some good answers :-)

Comment: Added, but I don't really think its relevant. I'm asking because I'm not even sure if its supported. Its not mentioned anywhere in the docs nor can I find any example of it online

Comment: Are you trying to use the validate plugin to also submit the form?  I don't think it should be used that way.  I think you should validate, and then if valid either submit the form or send an ajax request separately.

Comment: Yeah, I'll just send a separate ajax request. I wanted to use 'remote' to check both the username and the password, but looks like thats not possible/not the intended behavior